# “bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory” error when trying to install something

Tags: linux, bash, ruby, ruby-on-rails, zorin

I apologize, I don't have much experience with Linux. So I have ruby installed on my machine and I'm trying to install rails. When I do `gem install rails` I get a proper response

```
Successfully installed rails-6.0.3.2

1 gem installed
```

But when I do `rails --version` it returns the following:

```
bash: /usr/lib/command-not-found: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

What can be the issue here?

My machine is running on Zorin OS.
By the way here's some more information:
`temp-user@Lenovo-IdeaPad-S145-5:~$ ls -l /usr/bin | grep python`

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          23 Nov  7  2019 pdb3.6 -> ../lib/python3.6/pdb.py  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          23 Nov  7  2019 pdb3.7 -> ../lib/python3.7/pdb.py  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          31 Nov 26  2019 py3versions -> ../share/python3/py3versions.py  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          18 Jul  6 00:51 python -> /usr/bin/python2.7  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root           9 Mar 28 01:44 python3 -> python3.5  
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4526456 Nov  7  2019 python3.6  
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4526456 Nov  7  2019 python3.6m  
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4873376 Nov  7  2019 python3.7  
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4873376 Nov  7  2019 python3.7m  
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          10 Nov 26  2019 python3m -> python3.6m
```

at one point i might have tried to change python versions, but i don't remember exactly
in my `/usr/bin/` there are a lot of python's installed

```
python
python3
python3.6
python3.6m
python3.7
python3.7m
python3m
```

Comment: Did you a syste intallation or a user installation, you mention neither  `sudo` nor `--user-install`?

Comment: @xenoid just went with `gem install rails`, no `sudo`, so I guess it's a user installation?

Comment: On my Ubuntu, `gem install rails` fails because it tries to install system-wide. Which distro/version?

Comment: @xenoid Zorin OS 15

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/lib/command-not-found` is a piece of code that tries to make suggestions when the command you typed cannot be found (spelling errors, or suggests the installation of package that provide the command). It happens to be written in Python3, and Python3 may not be installed on your system (even though it's kind of mandatory on recent Linux distros...).

But you get this error because the `rails` command cannot be found. Since you ran the installation as a user space, `rails` is likely in some user directory that you have to add to your PATH (edit your `~/.profile`). You can use `gem list -d` to find the directory.

Comment: that didn't help unfortunately
so i just pasted `export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/temp-user/.gem"` into my `~/.profile`
as `gem list -d` said rails are installed here `/home/temp-user/.gem
`
but nothing has changed

Comment: Did you re-execute the profile (. ~/.profile)? You can also just execute `.export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/temp-user/.gem` in your current bash session.

Comment: yes, i did, but it didn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

```
apt install python
```

fixed it for me..